# roman numerals in page

Tags: page-numbering

Roman numerals in page numbers are required in the front matter of the thesis. But if I write `\frontmatter` in the ERT then on some pages the page numbers appear in roman numerals while on the others pages they do not. How can roman numerals in as page numbers be limited only in the front matter?

```
\batchmode
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{\/}}
\makeatother
\documentclass[english,openany]{book}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[LGR,T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter


\DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{\greektext #1}}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\~}{LGR}{126}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyrtext}{%
\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{T2A}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textcyr}[1]{\leavevmode{\cyrtext #1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareFontEncoding{T2A}{}{}}

\newcommand{\lyxmathsym}[1]{\ifmmode\begingroup\def\b@ld{bold}
\text{\ifx\math@version\b@ld\bfseries\fi#1}\endgroup\else#1\fi}


\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
 headsepline,
 ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\small}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\chapter
\section
\subsection
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

I am using `\makecontents` to make the contents of the chapter. but its does not include the contents of pages in frontmatter how can that be done?

Comment: Your 'MWE' does not compile!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'MWE' by the O.P. does not compile -- due to `\chapter` etc. commands without arguments.

`\begin{frontmatter}...\end{frontmatter}` is possible but of no use here.

The main culprit is that `\frontmatter` has no following `\mainmatter` command.

There are warnings by `scrlayer-scrpage` etc. about the headheight etc. I don't address this issues.

```
%\batchmode
%\makeatletter
%\def\input@path{{\/}}
%\makeatother
\documentclass[english,openany]{book}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[LGR,T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter


\DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{\greektext #1}}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\~}{LGR}{126}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyrtext}{%
\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{T2A}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textcyr}[1]{\leavevmode{\cyrtext #1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareFontEncoding{T2A}{}{}}

\newcommand{\lyxmathsym}[1]{\ifmmode\begingroup\def\b@ld{bold}
\text{\ifx\math@version\b@ld\bfseries\fi#1}\endgroup\else#1\fi}


\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
 headsepline,
 ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\small}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Foobar}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see all the page numbers are coming in roman numerals while I want only that the pages staring form Chapter 1 should not have roman numerals How can that be done?

Comment: @user87834: See the screen shot produced by my code: `Chapter 1 Foobar` has arabic page numbers, the unnumbered frontmatter one has roman page numbers. If you don't see it, you're doing something totally different and the above 'MWE' is not corresponding!

Comment: @user87834 Directly above you say it works, so apparently this is a new question? Apart from that, i don't understand the comment. Where is `\makecontents` defined?

Comment: Okay I will make a new question. This question is in addition to the one I asked before.