# Contents using roman numerals

Tags: table-of-contents, front-matter

I am using `\tableofcontents` to make the contents of the chapter. but its does not include the contents of pages in frontmatter how can that be done?

```
\documentclass[english,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subscript}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter
\usepackage{amsmath}


\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{}
\tableofcontents{}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
 \mainmatter
\chapter
\end {document}
```

Comment: Your MWE doesn't contain `\makecontents` ... And please, be so kind and remove from MWE all what is not necessary to show your problem.

Comment: This is a follow up to [roman numerals in page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285531)

Comment: Edited MWE is much better, however still contain packages, which are surplus for your problem. Also loading `\ampsmath` package not need `\makeatletter...\makeatother` construct.

Comment: `\tableofcontents` is doing that for the present book class that I am using.But the chapters specified under `\frontmatter` are not included.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot change the starred form. What else can be done in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[english,openany]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{babel}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
 \mainmatter
\chapter{First}
    \end{document}
```

As you can see, the chapter in front matter should not be of starred form to be included in table of contents. Since it is in front matter, it will not be numbered.

BTW, your question title is miss leading. Change it so, that it will reflect your problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFisher, thank your for correction `start` to `starred` ...